# Update not performed

Tags: php, mysql, csv, batch-file

I prepare a script which update the field "stock" in the database of my online shop.
When I run it ther's no No errors who appears ! However no change occurs at the database
So what can be the problem ! It can't access to the database because of it's name ?

Any idea? 
Here is the code below :

```
<?php
/*---------------------CONNEXION MYSQL----------------------*/

$servername='';
$database_username='';
$database_password='';
$database_name='';

set_time_limit(1600);
$link = mysql_connect($servername, $database_username, $database_password);
//$link = mysql_connect('mysql5-6.240', 'vintagemvm75', 'pu1df4mu');
if (!$link) {
    die('Connexion impossible : ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connecté correctement';



//$link = mysql_connect($servername,$database_username,$database_password) or die("Erreur de connexion au serveur"); //mysql_connect
//mysql_select_db($link, $database_name) or die("Erreur de connexion à la BDD"); //old: mysql_select_db

/*---------------------FIN CONNEXION MYSQL----------------------*/


/*---------------------RÉCUPÉRATION DU FICHIER STOCK et INITIALISATION----------------------*/

$fichier = file("../batch/export_solsys.csv");
$fp = fopen("../batch/export_solsys.csv","r");

$upc= "";
$stock="";
$ligne = 1; 

/*---------------------FIN RÉCUP----------------------*/


echo("Parcours du fichier...")."<br/>";
/*---------------------MISE A JOUR DU STOCK----------------------*/
while($tab=fgetcsv($fp,1000,';'))
{      
            $champs = count($tab);//nombre de champs dans la ligne en question  
            $ligne++;
            $upc = $tab[0];
            $stock = $tab[7];

            echo("upc: ").$upc."<br/>";
            echo("stock: ").$stock."<br/>";

$batch = "SELECT stock FROM declinaison_stock_produit where upc = '56939'";
$requete = mysql_query($batch, $link);

$batch1 ="UPDATE declinaison_stock_produit SET stock = '4' where upc = '56939'";
$requete1 = mysql_query($batch1, $link);        


             echo("Stock mis à jour  ");
             echo("Fin de l'éxécution du batch");

}
?>
```

Comment: You also need to select a **database** using `mysql_select_db()`. I **strongly** suggest that you switch to using something like `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: You never check for errors. Why you know that there is no error?

Comment: When I tried to use mysql_select_database It didn't accept it ! I thought that the version of Php of my shop is very old that's why I didn't use mysqli! So what can I do ? ther's an uncomment code with select database check it and tell me if it's right or not

Comment: You also open the `.csv` and read it all into an array `$fichier = file("../batch/export_solsys.csv");` then you open it with a file handle `$fp = fopen("../batch/export_solsys.csv","r");` and read it line by line??? Might be better to get someone who knows some PHP to do this for you. Or at least spend some time [reading the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not filled out your connection variables that are being passed to `mysql_connect`.
Moreover, you are not even using `mysql_select_db()`, to connect to database. It should be something like:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, $database_name);
```

Otherwise, provide the database name in `mysql_connect()` in the following manner:

```
$link = mysql_connect($servername, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
```

You need to have these variables filled out in order to connect to the database:

```
$servername='';
$database_username='';
$database_password='';
$database_name='';
```

*You have commented out the lines where you hard-coded them.*